# Advice on SignalR architecture

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I need some advice on how to use SignalR on a specific task.

Specifically, I have a legacy ASP.NET application which is modernized on the go, by rewriting existing modules, or adding new functionalities as client-side modules (html5/css/js) with webapi-based backend.

I need to integrate SignalR to accomplish tasks as follows:

1. js code on a webpage makes an ajax request. The code on server can take long time, so I don't want to have to wait for ajax code to complete.
   For example, send an email having attached a couple of SSRS reports rendered as PDF. I don't want to force user to wait until all the reports are rendered (this can take sometime tens of seconds). So my code just calls ajax, but use no handler for success or error
2. In webapi method, when completed successfully, I want to send a SignalR message to client, with success statue (and maybe some additional info)
3. If any error occurs in webapi, I want to send a SignalR message to client with error information
4. In web app in master page I want to include SignalR code which will initialize on page load, and will receive the notifications sent by server code.
   It will then process the messages as needed (report the error, success, etc).

Can you provide some guidance and code reference?

Thank you

Comment: What you're describing is a standard use case for signalR. I suggest you go through this tutorial http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr and you will get an idea of how to use signalR in your app.

Comment: I checked that already, but I didn't found how to send message from server to client, e.g. how to access and call signalR code from my webapi method to send data to client. And how to register signalR at application's startup. My app is legacy app, with global.asax AppStart, and I don't understand how this fits with owin startup initialization

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out the solution.
Something similar with what I need is described in [Server broadcast with SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr)